# How can I get the devices battery level in javascript

Tags: javascript, battery

I am doing a network call every 15 seconds in my app, and if the users device battery percent is lower than 20%, than I would like to do the call every 30 seconds instead. How do I get the user's devices current battery level? Is it possible? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Man i don't know whether its done till now or not but I am inspired by the way you are going and considering things. Really appreciate.

Comment: I don't want to use up the users battery

Comment: up vote from my side. +1 and put it under my favorite.

Comment: Thanks, I am still searching on it

Comment: I think I found something here, but the battery api isnt supported on many modern browsers, like opera: https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-battery-status-api/

Comment: Looks like my answer wasnt working on firefox mac, so I deleted it.

Comment: After having a quick look, it seems to me that it is not possible in browsers like Safari.

Comment: Looks like that to me as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [Battery Status API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Battery_Status_API). It doesn't work in all browsers, but it's a start.

For browsers that support it, something like this should work:

```js
navigator.getBattery().then(function(battery) {
  battery.addEventListener('levelchange', function() {    
    // Do stuff when the level changes, you can get it
    // from battery.level
    document.write((battery.level*100)+"%");
  })
  document.write((battery.level*100)+"%");
});
```

Comment: Does IE support it? Does microsoft Edge support it?

Comment: @KingCoder11 There's a link the answer... ;)

Comment: @Andreas, Whoops, didn't see that, my bad

Comment: Looks like IE, Safari, Edge, and Android has no support

Comment: note, even in browsers that **do** support this API, it may not be that simple. For example, from Firefox 52 onwards, the Battery Status API is only available in chrome/privileged code (in other words, "add ons")